# Connect to a SQL Server database present in another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlconnection

I am trying to connect to a database that is present in another server using the below code:

```
dbConnection.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};" + "Server=ServerName;" +
           "Uid=exchange\\s***;" + "Pwd=*******;" + "DataBase=Sample Data v2;";
dbConnection.Open();
```

It is giving me login error. I tested the SQL connection using the ODBC connection manager and it is showing connection successfully. But I am not able to connect to the database from my c# code. Is there something wrong in the connection string?

Thanks

Comment: Does the user has access to the "Sample Data v2" database.?

Comment: Yes It has access. In database exchange\\s*** is dbOwner

Comment: Is this web based application or desktop application. And if web you can have web.config file and if desktop you can have application config file

Comment: @Sushri: You may tried out another connection string format then

Comment: @Damith I am creating a windows service application

Comment: what type is `dbConnection` is it a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
dbConnection.ConnectionString ="Data source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=Sample Data v2;;user id=s***;password=*******"
```

Answer (score 0):

// .NET DataProvider -- Standard Connection using System.Data.SqlClient;

```
dbConnection.ConnectionString ="Data Source=ServerIP;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User id=UserName;Password=Secret;";
dbConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Standard Security**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

**Trusted Connection**

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

**Connection to a SQL Server instance**

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Reference : [NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use StringConnectionBuilder if you are not sure how to format the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are developing a windows forms based application please try this process.

1. Add a app.config file. Follow this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx
2. Retrieve connection string from config file. Follow this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs

Please try this method.